# 'XAxis' object has no attribute '_gridOnMajor'

Tags: python, jupyter

`import mplleaflet

sample = listings.sample(1000)
plt.scatter(sample['longitude'], sample['latitude'])

mplleaflet.display()`

this is the error:
**AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute '_gridOnMajor'**

I'm getting error when i use `mplleaflet.display()`, but when i remove the `mplleaflet.display()` it is showing the plot but entirely different from what I'm expecting

Comment: _"it is showing the plot but entirely different from what I'm expecting"_ Perhaps it would help to tell more about what you observed exactly as opposed to what you had expected?

Comment: when i use mplleaflet.dispaly() What i expected is to plot points on the map, But when is use it it is showing me this error. If i skip that code alone then, no plotting is showing just getting out of the map alone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `mplleaflet 0.0.5` and `matplotlib 3.6.2`. I think mplleaflet is now incompatible with matplotlib.

I changed the file utils.py in the mplleaflet files in my environment. I simply replaced `axis._gridOnMajor` with `axis._major_tick_kw['gridOn']`.

See also:

- https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2913
- https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3624#issuecomment-1161805210